# Changes made to an address in Sawtooth?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

I have created an address and some payload serialised with protobuf. I have then stored this serialised bytes on this address

```
 context.set_state({address: account.SerializeToString()},
                                self._timeout)
```

Now, Lets say i have chnaged the payload and uploaded to this address. 
I just want to know, If i can get the history of all the changes made to this address alongwith the present payload stored at this address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: There is no immediate or obvious api to fetch the history of data for a specific address.

That being said, each transaction, as you know, does get a context which is what is then written through to global state. The merkle tree maintains that transaction context however.

You have three choices:

1. Using the `/blocks` endpoint, iterate through each transaction in each block. From the transaction use the `state root hash` field in the `head` field of the `/state` endpoint along with the address of interest.
2. Using the `/transactions` endpoint to get the list of transactions, using the same fields described in #1
3. Instrument your TP to emit Events and, using an off chain event listener, capture relevant information to an off-chain DB to index and queried as desired.